# External ubuntu does not boot on one machine

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, external-hdd

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.03 onto an external m.2. It boots up fine on the machine it was created on and on another machine, but not on a third machine. On the third machine it starts booting, then the pc shuts down and boots back to windows.

All of the systems are UEFI based

Both the machines where it works are made by asus and the machine where it doesn't work is HP

I have disabled fast and secure boot.

The thumb drive I used to install Ubuntu boots up fine on the HP.

I installed Ubuntu with no other drives connected except the LiveCD and the external drive

[UEFI boot settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK9kW.jpg)

[UEFI boot settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdNL5.jpg)

Comment: Do you get the Ubuntu boot menu? where you can select to start Ubuntu, or advance options?  If you do not get that menu, do you get it on the other machines?  

If you do not get it on any machine, then on one of the machines it boots edit /etc/default/grub change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown and GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 to GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Then reboot confirming you now have the boot menu.  Then boot on the HP, go to advance options, and add acpi=off to cmd line.  If that does not work, can you post any errors or logs?

Comment: The menu did not come up on the systems on which it boots. I changed the things you recommended me to, but the menu still did not appear. What should I do now?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention you need to run "update-grub" for the changes to apply.

Comment: if you are sure all the systems are uefi you can also try to install "refind" from apt, refind is a boot manager for EFI-based systems.   I am curious as to why you are wanting one drive to boot on 3 machines? what is the final goal?

Comment: Got that menu working now, but the same problem persists on the hp. End goal is to have a drive that i can use on both of my work computers. I used the second laptop just for testing. I actually only need it to run on the computer I installed Ubuntu from and the hp.

Comment: If you are geetting that menu on the other pc, but not the HP it means you are not entering the boot process of that drive.  Check your uefi settings, make sure it is set to boot uefi and not legacy.  You could also try, boot from the usb liveCD, then mount the drive, mount the run/sys/dev/proc directory with mount - R to the same directory on the drive, and chroot to it, then run update-grub.  But I suspect your HP is booting off legacy and not uefi.